# Marketo Dyanmically moving leads

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, marketo

In Wordpress, I am using Gravity forms with Marketo plugin. Currently, you are able to create a form and select a Marketo Feed or Campaign and then map the inputs. This is great if you want one form to go to one campaign. There is no way for me to changes feeds or campaigns dynamically through this [marketo plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/marketo/) based upon a campaign code(`https://website.com?variable=campaign`).

**So, the big questions is:**

Is there way in Marketo to move leads from one campaign to another dynamically based on campaign without making duplicates?

So basically, right now I have a form that is plugged into like a catch all campaign. I would like a lead to move out of that catch all campaign and move to the campaign that is in the campaign variable provided (`https://website.com?variable=campaign`)

Comment: You would be able to easily do this with a proper Gravity Forms add-on, but that plugin hasn't been updated in 2 years as the author has moved on. Did you try https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-post-to-3rd-party/? I can at least work with you to get it working for your use-case.

Comment: HI!, Thanks for the reply. I haven't even heard of it. Where can I get it?